# Something strange with added in Android Studio .jar lib

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

I added in my `Android Studio Project` .jar library.

When I try to use its classes (an example `NumberUtils` class) inside a package directory, `Android Studio` is not see classes (but I know, that they exist):

[image]

But when I create class out of package directory - it's all ok:

[image]

How can I use it insida a package?

Edit:
[image]

Edit 2:
[image]

Comment: Try compiling the class using gradle build.

Comment: Manually Import that package where you need to use it.

Comment: @Srinivasan, do you mean write "import somelib.*;'?

Comment: once clean the project and run..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Srinivasan show right way for resolving this problem.

This lib didn't have a package name, only classes inside. But when I added package name inside jar library - it bacame to work (when I use 'import' phrase).

Answer (score 1):

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

tells the build system that any JAR file inside app/libs is a dependency and should be included in the compilation classpath and in the final package.

So no need to add again like

```
compile files('libs/NumberToWordsLib.jar')
```

Remove this then sync and rebuild your project. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Nope... It is not help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a dependent library, from file->projectstructure->dependencies

and also after adding the new library as dependency, you have to do a clean Build, usually it does a gradle synch automatically, if you add new library

**EDIT**

I do not see any package declarations there

Comment: package net.somewhere.testapp; at first pic